# Ubuntu apache create valid self-signed certificate ssl https (remove connection is not secure)

Tags: apache, http, ubuntu, ssl, ssl-certificate

I had configured Ubuntu apache use use self-signed certificate with ssl and https. I followed here https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-for-apache-in-ubuntu-16-04.

But it seems that it is "Not secure", "Connection is not secure", and "invalid" certificate. Is there the way to create a SSL certificate file to install on browser such as Firefox or Chrome to get rid of "Not secure", "Connection is not secure", and "invalid" or to create a valid one?

Answer (score -2):

Get one from https://letsencrypt.org/ or purchase one from a certificate authority.

Comment: Hello, Thank You!
I just heard that we can create our own self-signed certificate that allows Firefox or Chrome to install and It become get rid of "Connection is not secure" or a valid certificate.